# React, getting undefined as result while using useContext

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to get `state` and `setState` from the `Store` file but I get `undefined`. What's happening, and how do fix it?

```js
import React, {createContext, useState} from 'react'
import Header from './Header'

export const Data = createContext()


function Store() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(false)
  const  value = {state, setState}

  return (
    <Data.Provider value={value}>
      <Header/>
    </Data.Provider>
  )
}

export default Store
```

```js
import React, { useContext} from "react";
import { Data } from "./Store";

function Header() {
  const Store = useContext(Data)
  
  console.log(Store) // I get undefined

  return (
    <div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating `Store`, but never calling it, that's the problem. Wrap `App` component inside `Store` and it would work. Working example of your link [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-smoke-26qmqm?file=/src/index.js).

index.js:

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import Store from "./store";
import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <Store>
      <App />
    </Store>
  </StrictMode>
);
```